# Removing an OnClickListener on a view remove all touch events on the views behind

Tags: android, view, onclicklistener

I have a top bar layout with a header, a vertical menu and a transparent background view.

When the `btn_menu` is pressed, the vertical menu is opened using an animation. When the menu is open, I set an `OnClickListener` on the transparent background view which closes the menu when the transparent background is clicked. When closing the menu, I remove the `OnClickListener` from the background view, using:

```
mTopBarBg.setOnClickListener(null);
```

The problem is that it seems to remove all the touch events of the views behind it (set in the `content_container` of the main layout). Eg. a `ViewPager` which does not detect swipe anymore, or a `ListView` which does not scroll and can't be clicked anymore, while they worked correctly before.

What's wrong?

**in top bar fragment**

```
private void toggleMenu(int duration){
    if(mMenuIsOpen){

        TranslateAnimation anim1 = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,-(mHeight-mMenuVerticalOffset));
        anim1.setFillAfter(true);
        anim1.setDuration(duration);
        mVerticalMenu.setAnimation(anim1);

        AlphaAnimation anim2 = new AlphaAnimation(0.7f, 0.0f);
        anim2.setFillAfter(true);
        anim2.setDuration(duration);
        mTopBarBg.setAnimation(anim2);

        mTopBarBg.setOnClickListener(null);

        mMenuIsOpen = false;
    }
    else{

        TranslateAnimation anim1 = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,-(mHeight-mMenuVerticalOffset),0);
        anim1.setFillAfter(true);
        anim1.setDuration(duration);
        mVerticalMenu.setAnimation(anim1);

        AlphaAnimation anim2 = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 0.7f);
        anim2.setFillAfter(true);
        anim2.setDuration(duration);
        mTopBarBg.setAnimation(anim2);

        mTopBarBg.setOnClickListener(mBgClickListener);

        mMenuIsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

**main layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/mainbg" 
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="44dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_bar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipChildren="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**top bar layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00000000" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/top_bar_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/vertical_menu"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <!-- vertical menu layout -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:background="#ffffff" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_menu"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:background="@drawable/menubtn" />       

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_menu"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**top bar with menu open**

[image]

Comment: Try to also use `setClickable(false)` with your invisible View.

Comment: I ended up using onTouchListener to control wether the listener consumes the event or not, but your solution seems to work too. Put it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to also use `setClickable(false)` on your overlay `View`. Using the `setOnClickListener()` method makes the `View` clickable and this probably "eats" your future events(even after using `null` as that doesn't modify the previous set clickable property).

As a side not your layout is very complicated in relation to what you try to do. More precisely the layout is deeper than it should be. There is no point in having a `FrameLayout` container when it has the same properties as the `RelativeLayout` of your bar(you could use an `include` tag to include the bar without the need for that extra `FrameLayout`). You coud also lose the `top_bar_bg` `View` and set the listener directly on the root `RelativeLayout`.
Last, the inner `RelativeLayout`(header) could be removed and replaced by properly positioning the child views in the root `Relativelayout` with a white empty `View` under them(with the appropriate dimensions to simulate the white background).

Comment: I'd like to add that you need to do `setClickable(false)` _after_ `setOnClickListener(null)`. The property is kept as true if you do it otherwise, and your overlay keeps preventing views behind it from being clicked. I was wondering why it wasn't working for me, but that's because I was setting the clickable property before the null listener.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing `onClickListener` you can do one thing.Always set the `onClickListener` and use a `boolean variable` to trace the menu on and off. So your code will be something like

```
 boolean is_menu_open = false;
 public void onClick(View v){
        if(is_menu_open){
             hidemenu;
             is_menu_open = false;
        } else
             do nothing
  }
```

and whenever you shows the menu then set `is_menu_open` to `true`

Comment: The problem is that `onClick` consumes the event, and touch listener of views behind are not triggered.